# Enter an array and get the index of elements in Angular js

Tags: angularjs, arrays

I have an input text area where the type is an array.  I would like to know if there is a way, once the user enters the data in the text area in comma seperated form to list the array, is there a way to get the index of the elements entered in the array. Below is the code

```
<label>Enter values in comma separated way ex: s1,s22</label>

    <textarea class="form-control" type="text" data-ng-model="arrColNames" ng-list required
    name="arrColNames" required minlength="0"
    placeholder="Name,Age,X,Y"
    class="form-control"></textarea>
<textarea id="test" class="form-control"  style="margin-top:2%; width: 60%;" rows="10" >
Resulting definition:<![CDATA[<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Tgtcols>
<tcol index="{{$index}}">{{arrColNames}}</tcol>
</Tgtcols>
]]> 
</textarea>
```

when the user enters the values in the text area in comma seperated form, how can I get the index of elements in the array 'arrColNames'. 
In the above example, when the user enters the input like s1,s2, the arrColNames values gets populated in the textarea with id="test". But i wanted the index of elements in the array also to get populated. 
To eloborate further, Im looking for something like below. If the user enters the below values in the textarea

```
Textarea input c1,c2,c3

expected output 
<tcol index=[0,1,2]>["c1","c2","c3"]</tcol>
```

Any help on this is much appreciated. Thanks in Advance

Comment: what does index of element mean to you , can you explain exactly what you need.?

Comment: "But i wanted the index of elements in the array also to get populated" can you provide some example how its gonna look like . Provide some example with data.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply provide the ng-bind="arrColNames", in your second text area with id="test". Also, to get the indexes, you can create a watch function on "arrColNames" property, split it on "," and assign it to another array property.
e.g.

```
$scope.arr = [];
$scope.$watch('arrColNames', function(newValue, oldValue){
    arr = newValue.split(',');
})
```